# How do I Create a Collection of Generic Types?

Tags: c#, generics

**NOTE:** .NET Pad code [HERE](http://dotnetpad.net/ViewPaste/TFHGZvifyEub1w5_e1QF1g#c25,c58,c74,c114,c132,).

I have a base class that takes a generic type  parameter.

Each class it will form the base of has a corresponding *Collection Class* which consists of only this:

```
public class List_SomeType : List<SomeTime> {
  public List_SomeType() {
  }
}
```

That's it: It only a [List<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) container.

However, it is posing a problem in my base class because one of the methods is to return this collection.

I tried creating the following **Get** method, which made perfect sense to me:

```
public TList Get() {
  var list = new TList();
  using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(SP_GET, m_openConn)) {
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    using (var r = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
      while (r.Read()) {
        list.Add(FillDataRecord(r));
      }
    }
    cmd.Connection.Close();
  }
  return list;
}

public class TList : List<T> {
  public TList() { }
}
```

In my derived class, I planned to call this base class as follows:

```
public class BuyerDB : DAL_Base<Buyer> {

  private static BuyerDB one;

  static BuyerDB() {
    one = new BuyerDB();
  }

  public static BuyerList GetBuyerList() {
    return (BuyerList)one.Get(); // <= ERROR HERE!
  }

}
```

The ERROR HERE states:

> Cannot convert type 'DAL_Base.TList' to 'BuyerList'

**How do I convert back to a collection of my generic types?**

### EDIT:

Mark wants to know what `BuyerList` is.

I thought that was understood from what I wrote.

Apparently not, so here it is:

```
public class BuyerList : List<Buyer> { }
```

That's all!

Comment: where is `BuyerList` declared? And why not just `List<Buyer>` ? Why does `TList` / `BuyerList` *exist* ?

Comment: Your example above is either missing some necessary code, or you've been liberal with your consistency between code chunks...

Comment: `BuyerList`, as stated, is simply `public class BuyerList : List<T> { }`. I didn't realize I need to explicitly show that, but I can. Hang on....

Comment: @MarcGravell: Did the edit help?

Comment: @jp2code a bit: have added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This compiles:

```
public static BuyerList getBuyerList() {
  var result = new BuyerList();
  result.AddRange(one.Get());
  return result;
}
```

I am not sure why the other list would not work, but I'd guess it has something to do with checks done inside of the C# language.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `DAL_Base<T>`, and that has a nested type: `Dal_Base<T>+TList`, which is `: List<T>`. That's fine, but that is nothing *whatsoever* to do with a `BuyerList`, so the two are not compatible, any more than `B` and `C` are compatible (they aren't) here:

```
class A {}
class B : A {}
class C : A {} // cannot assign a B to a C or a C to a B
```

I would suggest you completely forget about `Dal_Base<T>+TList` and `BuyerList`, and just use a `List<T>` / `List<Buyer>`:

```
public List<T> Get() {
  var list = new List<T>;
  using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(SP_GET, m_openConn)) {
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    using (var r = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
      while (r.Read()) {
        list.Add(FillDataRecord(r));
      }
    }
    cmd.Connection.Close();
  }
  return list;
}
....
public static List<Buyer> GetBuyerList() {
    return one.Get();
}
```

I would also suggest you take a look at "dapper", perhaps just using:

```
 public List<T> Get() {
     return m_openConn.Query<T>(SP_GET, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure)
                      .ToList();
}
```

although in reality, "get all the rows without a filter" methods are rarely desirable.

Comment: Unfortunately, this project was already designed using `BuyerList`, so converting all of the classes to use `List<Buyer>` would brake lots of code. As for moving `DAL_Base<T>+TList`, I had already noticed that as well and have moved `TList` outside of `DAL_Base<T>`, but I still can not convert.

Comment: I added a link to this [.NET Pad Project](http://dotnetpad.net/ViewPaste/TFHGZvifyEub1w5_e1QF1g#c25,c58,c74,c114,c132,). You can't compile it, but all of the code is there ...if it helps!

Comment: @jp2code in that case, you have two choices: 1: change the DAL to be double-generic, and accept the list type in addition to the entity type, or 2: just populate a `new BuyerList` with whatever objects you get back from `one.Get`

Comment: i.e. `BuyerList GetBuyerList() { var fromDal = one.Get(); var list = new BuyerList(); foreach(var obj in fromDal) list.Add(obj); return list;`

Comment: Ah. Essentially what I wrote as my own answer. [SO](http://stackoverflow.com) never posted your comments to me until just now, though.

Comment: @jp2code basically the same, yes; `AddRange` is a better method to use - good spot